# How do I change the root directory Angular CLI uses for generating tests?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-test, angular-cli-v7

In my project we use the angular CLI to generate new components and services, but we'd like to move the tests into their own root directory that mirrors the sourceRoot `src`.

For example, instead of:

```
> ng generate service shared/services/test-service --dry-run
CREATE src/app/shared/services/test-service.service.spec.ts (359 bytes)
CREATE src/app/shared/services/test-service.service.ts (140 bytes)
```

The output would be

```
> ng generate service shared/services/test-service --dry-run
CREATE test/app/shared/services/test-service.service.spec.ts (359 bytes)
CREATE test/app/shared/services/test-service.service.ts (140 bytes)
```

I have looked through the documentation for a configuration option to specify this behavior and haven't found anything. Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Here's the version information in case it's relevant:

```
Angular CLI: 7.2.3
Node: 8.10.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.1.4
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for your case?

Comment: No @Kosmonaft we decided that if it is this difficult to mirror the directories (not possible without a hack?) we are better off to keep our project consistent with how the angular designers intended.